# Apple TV 2 won't update YouTube app?

Tags: appletv, youtube

Recently, Google [updated the YouTube App](http://www.engadget.com/2014/12/09/apple-tv-youtube-update/) for Apple TV, revamping the whole UI. <strike>Because I love watching ads</strike> Because the new version has all content accessible and an improved UI, I would like to upgrade to it.

However, my Apple TV has not automatically updated the channel. I did get the other channels which came out around the same time as this YouTube update.

I've tried rebooting the Apple TV (soft and hard) as well as checking System > General > Software Updates, but no luck.

Is there another way to force an update? Or, is perhaps the update itself limited to Apple TV 3? I would like to know either way before I go through the hassle of a firmware re-install...

Comment: It's even worse nowadays. Google changed the youtube API and now the ATV2 won't play any youtube videos anymore. Any hints on how to solve this? I am already using PlexConnect to watch Plex content on my ATV2.

Comment: If you have an iPhone/iPad, you can stream YouTube to your ATV from there. Not as convenient as running it on the ATV directly, but better than nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The updated YouTube app requires Apple TV Software Update 7.0 which is only available for 3rd generation Apple TV.

[About Apple TV (2nd and 3rd generation) software updates](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202157)

[Find out which Apple TV you have](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT200008)

[How to update software on your Apple TV](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT200008)